# What causes the InvalidEntity exception in the SFDC bulk api?

Tags: salesforce

When creating a new bulk job through the API, I am getting an InvalidEntity as an exception code which isn't in [SFDC's docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/api_bulk.pdf) (pdf)

I'm making the following request

```
https://na13-api.salesforce.com/services/async/24.0/job

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <operation>query</operation>
  <object>Campaign</object>
  <concurrencyMode>Parallel</concurrencyMode>
  <contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

And I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><error
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
 <exceptionCode>InvalidEntity</exceptionCode>
 <exceptionMessage>Entity 'Campaign' is not supported by the Bulk API.</exceptionMessage>
</error>
```

I've excluded the headers but I do have accept & content encoding specified as gzip and the content is gzipped when it is sent and received.

The requests work correctly for

- Lead
- Contact
- Opportunity
- Task
- Event
- OpportunityContactRole
- Account
- CampaignMember
- Note
- Profile
- RecordType
- User

I only get the exception shown above for:

- Campaign
- UserLicense
- OpportunityStage
- OpportunityHistory
- LeadHistory

I'm only using the bulk api to download csv's out of salesforce and I've only tried the above entities because I don't need any others.

Comment: Hi Paul, same problem here. I get InvalidEntity on AccountHistory. I think is somehow related to the 'readonly' nature of the entities. This should not be blocking for SELECTs. But, for bulk-api selects you also need admin rights, so I think the problem is somewhat related to the readonly-ness.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a very long time, but I think you can get this exception if one of your foreign key relationships is incorrect.